# Facebook C# SDK App Request

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to create an app request using the Facebook C# SDK but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Hello World!";
parameters.data = "Custom Data Here";

dynamic result = fb.Post("me/apprequests", parameters);
var id = result.id;
```

If I understand well it should show me a dialog box displaying a list of friends from which I can select but instead I don't see anything.

Would somebody also know how to get the list of facebook ids after the post has successfully occurred?

Thank you.

Jon

Answer (score -1):

Here is source code for what you are trying to do, this is plain JavaScript SDK.

call following JavaScript function on your button click or similar:

```
function InviteFriends(){
                 var ResponseIds = FB.ui({
                       method : 'apprequests',
                       message: 'Your personal message herer',
                 },
                 function(ResponseIds ) {
                          console.log("IDS : " + ResponseIds.request_ids);
                }
          );}
```

Make sure you have following code in body tag
$

```
<div id="fb-root">  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR_APPID_HERE', //read your appid dynamically from codebehind C#
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that we can't do this type of requests using the Facebook C# SDK?

Comment: @Jon  Of course it should be possible to do similar request using Facebook C# SDK. Above is working example I was using, so thought will share with you. Is there any reason you want to use sever side code? Few tips: Just make sure you have set up all values in config file correctly. Also post error you are getting when you call above function.